# Does .trim() remove commas? (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, trim

I'm a bit confused as to how this comma is getting deleted in order for my parseFloat to work. Here is the information I'm reading from, as an example:`

```
541.0, 387.0

            String num[] = in.nextLine().split(",");
            // Trim and then parseFloat for x and y
            float x = Float.parseFloat(num[0].trim());
            float y = Float.parseFloat(num[1].trim());
```

The num[] splits this information by comma and thus we end up with:

num[0] = 541.0,

num[1] = 387.0

Then when I call trim the comma goes away. From my understanding trim only removed whitespace? Can someone explain this?

Comment: `split()` is removing the comma.

Comment: `Trim()` is not what is removing your comma. It's the `split()` method that is.

Comment: @dj1121 - `trim()` removes all leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Ohhh I got totally confused looking in the debugger. The debugger shows commas to seperate indexes and so I was getting all confused. Thank you!

Comment: BTW you can use - `split("\\s*,\\s*")` in case you don't want to use `trim()`

Comment: Hello all. Actually, the `parseDouble()` calls trim (source code linked in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36578155/1692706) below). So, trimming a string simply for the purpose OP is using it for, is not required in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`trim` does *not* remove commas, no.

`split` *does* remove the delimiter passed. So `split(",")` removes the commas.

Be aware that some locales (e.g. France) use a comma for the decimal separator: `Float.parseFloat()` (which is locale-independent and *always* uses a `.` as the decimal separator) *might* behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

[`[String].trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

From the docs,

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.
>
> If this String object represents an empty character sequence, or the
>   first and last characters of character sequence represented by this
>   String object both have codes greater than '\u0020' (the space
>   character), then a reference to this String object is returned.
>
> Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020'
>   in the string, then a new String object representing an empty string
>   is created and returned.
>
> Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string
>   whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the
>   last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'. A
>   new String object is created, representing the substring of this
>   string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the
>   character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m+1).
>
> This method may be used to trim whitespace (as defined above) from the
>   beginning and end of a string.

So, no. **Only** the leading and trailing whitespace is affected.

If you are interested, here is the [[source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29)].

Now, to see how the `,` is being removed. You have made a call to split.

[`[String].split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

From the docs,

> Splits this string ***around*** matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results
>   with these expressions:
>
> ```
> Regex     Result
> :     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
> o     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```

So, the delimiter, is removed and the string is `split` around it. As before, here is the [[source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%29)]. Following the hyperlink chain [will lead you here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29).

Referring to your post, `num[0] = 541.0,` **is not correct**. `num[0] = 541.0` (without the comma).

Moreover, you really don't need to call `trim()` since the `Double.parseDouble()` function already does that. [[main source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)] [[related](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29)] (see line 1009 in the second link)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `split()`, it uses the delimiter `,` and 'splits' your input into an array based on that. So the commas got removed there, not in your call to `trim().`

I don't know how you figured you got `num[0] = 541.0,`.

Answer (score 0):

Trim removes white spaces at the beginning and end of the word.

For example the word " test " become "test".